Как скачать файл с расширением .mp3.download?
Как скачать файл с расширением .mp3.download?
Сам файл, похоже, расширение .download это тоже самое, что и .part:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QF51OWtRnuYB0BVxirvSfOMAp9ODjUDo/view?usp=drivesdk
Файл остался после парсинга

ну просто берешь и скачиваешь файл, всё

@LolPopGames, Файл остался после парсинга
